# How to use filter method and find method at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use filter method and find method at the same time to sort, but it doesn't work well.

```
const nums = [
    17022,
    17027
]

const coupons = [
    {
        "coupon_id": 17022,
    },
    {
        "coupon_id": 17022,
    },
    {
        "coupon_id": 17024,
    },
    {
        "coupon_id": 17025,
    },
    {
        "coupon_id": 17026,
    },
    {
        "coupon_id": 17027,
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to is

```
couponsNew = coupons.filter(coupon => {
  return nums.find(id => coupon.coupon_id !== id)
})
```

to get couponsNew that coupon_id is not 17022, 17027.

Comment: Because `17022` !==  `17027` 
It  returns all

Comment: What is the expected output? Consider adding that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
const data = coupons.filter((d)=> !nums.includes(d.coupon_id));
console.log(data);
```